# Dom Document - extract a document id & save

Tags: php, oop, dom, domdocument

I am trying to extract a specific clump of HTML using dom document.

My code is as follows:

```
    $domd = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $domd->loadHTML($string);
    $this->hook = 'content';
    if($this->hook !== '') {
        $main = $domd->getElementById($this->hook);
        $newstr = "";
        foreach($main->childNodes as $node) {
            $newstr .= $domd->saveXML($node, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
        }
        $domd->loadHTML($newstr);
    }
    //MORE PARSING USING THE DOMD OBJECT
```

It works great BUT the foreach is quite slow, and I was wondering if there's a more intelligent way of doing this. I am re-loading the HTML into the $domd so I can keep editing. In the back of my mind I feel I should be saving a fragment, not re-loading the saved $newstr into the object.

Can this be made more elegant or faster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to mutate your existing `$domd` document, replacing it completely with those child nodes you're grabbing from that content node:

**UPDATE:** Just realized that since you were reloading using `loadHTML`, you probably wanted to preserve the `html`/`body` nodes that it creates. Code below has been adjusted to empty `body` and append the fragment there:

```
$domd = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$domd->loadHTML($string);
$this->hook = 'content';
if($this->hook !== '') {
    $main = $domd->getElementById($this->hook);
    $fragment = $domd->createDocumentFragment();
    while($main->hasChildNodes()) {
        $fragment->appendChild($main->firstChild);
    }
    $body = $domd->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0);
    while($body->hasChildNodes()) {
        $body->removeChild($body->firstChild);
    }
    $body->appendChild($fragment);
}
//MORE PARSING USING THE DOMD OBJECT
```